# Inverse image of maximal ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I would like to characterize the class of ring maps $f: A\to B$ between two commutative rings with identity such that for each maximal ideal $\mathfrak m\subset B$ the inverse image $f^{-1}(\mathfrak m)$ is maximal in $A$.

To begin with we give examples of such ring maps.

1. The class of all integral arrows $f: A\to B$, meaning that $B$ is integral over $f(A)$. This is standard fact from integral extensions. As an example take $k$ an algebraically closed field and consider $A, B$ two finitely generated $k$-algebra, which are both finite over $k$ by Zariski’s lemma. Then if there is a ring map $f: A\to B$ it follows that $B$ is finite over $f(A)$ thus integral.
2. If $A$ is a Jacobson ring, or equivalently, if for the inclusion map $i: A\to A[x]$ we have for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $A[x]$, $f^{-1}(\mathfrak m)$ is maximal in $A$, then for two finitely generated $A$-algebras $S,K$, every arrow $S\to K$ satisfies the desired condition. Just note that finitely generated algebra over a Jacobson ring is also Jacobson.

Also note an evident counterexample: Take the inclusion $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Q$.

Also note that composition of two ring maps with the “maximal inverse maximal” property satisfies the property as well.

There are integral arrows $A\to B$ such that $B$ is not a finitely generated $A$-algebra so that the class $1$ above is not contained in class $2$. Also for the Jacobson ring $\Bbb Z$ the arrow $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z[x]$ is not integral so that class $2$ is not contained in class $1$ either.

Does these provide sufficient clues to give a complete classification?

Comment: What about faithfully flat ring homomorphisms ?